# Angular Upgrade Error : 5.2.0 -> 6.0.9

Tags: angular, upgrade, angular6

I am getting below error when migrating my application from Angular 5.2.10 to 6.0.9. I used the migration steps described [here](https://update.angular.io/)

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ApplicationRef -> Injector]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ApplicationRef -> Injector]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Injector!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1034)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1271)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1216)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1113)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1271)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1216)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1113)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8161)
    at _createClass (core.js:8208)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8178)
```

Error Message Screenshot

[image]

**Angular version**: 6.0.9

**Browser**:

- [X] Chrome (desktop) version  67.0.3396.99

**Other Info**:

- Node version: 8.9.4
- Platform:  Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved by created a new Angular6 application and moving existing application code into that. Automatic upgrade mentioned [here](https://update.angular.io/) doesn't work.